# passing $scope objects to ng-if and ng-class ternary condition not working

Tags: javascript, angularjs

```
 **main.js:**

     $scope.status = [
            {name:'SQL', stat:"up"},
            {name:'Web Server', stat:"down"},
            {name:'Index', stat:"down"}
        ];

**index.html:**
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td ng-repeat="x in status">
        <div ng-if="{{x.name}}=='SQL'"> {{x.stat}} </div>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>

    <table>
      <tr>
        <td ng-repeat="x in status">
          <div ng-if="{{x.name}}=='SQL'" ng-class="{{x.stat}}=='up'? 'squareGreen':'squareRed'"> {{x.name +" : "+x.stat}} </div>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
```

I am trying to pass status array to index.html to compare the 'name' to a string then apply class squaregreen or red depending upon comparison of 'stat' to 'up' or 'down'. The goal is to match the name of the server and apply green when up and red when down. I have 2 problems below. 1. parse error in syntax for ng-if 2. all servers are applied Squarered, though 1st server(sql)'s 'stat' is 'up'

Answer (score 1):

Remove all the curly braces from your `ng-if` and `ng-class` expressions and it should work. E.G:

**main.js:**

```
 $scope.status = [
        {name:'SQL', stat:"up"},
        {name:'Web Server', stat:"down"},
        {name:'Index', stat:"down"}
    ];

**index.html:**
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td ng-repeat="x in status">
        <div ng-if="x.name=='SQL'"> {{x.stat}} </div>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>

    <table>
      <tr>
        <td ng-repeat="x in status">
          <div ng-if="x.name=='SQL'" ng-class="x.stat=='up'? 'squareGreen':'squareRed'"> {{x.name +" : "+x.stat}} </div>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
```

Curly braces are not necessary here because `ng-if` and `ng-class` bindings are evaluated as scope expressions already. Use curly braces when a directive does not do this by default (e.g. with '@' bindings). [AngularJS docs on scope binding](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngIf)

Answer (score 0):

Take out your curly braces.  `ng-if="x.name === 'SQL'"`

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use the extrapolation `{{}}` operator within `ng-if` and you need to use the `{}` within your `ng-class`

```
 <div ng-if="x.name == 'SQL'" ng-class="{x.stat=='up'? 'squareGreen':'squareRed'}"> {{x.name +" : "+x.stat}} </div>
```